# jquery .html does not trigger onclick?

Tags: jquery, triggers, onclick

I have a problem with .html, is it possible it does not trigger onClick? 
And if so, can someone advise me an alternative?

```
var textSubgenres ="";
    for(i=0; i<data3.length; i++)
    {
        if(i==0)
        {
            textSubgenres= textSubgenres+"<a href='#/genre/"+data3[i]+"' class='linkSubgenre' onClick='getInformation("+data3[i]+")'>"+data3[i]+" </a>";
        }
        else
        {
            textSubgenres= textSubgenres+", <a href='#/genre/"+data3[i]+"' class='linkSubgenre' onClick='getInformation("+data3[i]+")'>"+data3[i]+" </a>";
        }
    }
$("#subgenreText").html(textSubgenres);
```

Comment: Don't use inline event attributes. HTML belongs in .html files, CSS belongs in .css files and JS belongs in .js files. What's the point of adding jQuery if you're not even going to use it's normalized event management?

Comment: found solution it is onClick=getInformation('"+data3[i]+"')>"

Comment: A better solution would be to use event delegates. You should review the [jQuery api](http://api.jquery.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider splitting up your code in a more clear way, which involves not using inline `onClick` event handlers but rather use jQuery's event handling mechanics.

I've created a jsFiddle with a heavily commented demo here: [click](http://jsfiddle.net/g5FNd/35/)